# Further details on DMCA-removed post

Tags: support, legal, dmca-notice

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41783867/111794) was deleted in response to a DMCA request.

As far as I can tell, my answer does not contain any copyright content. The question also doesn't seem to contain any copyright content.

Where can I get further details as to which parts of the question / answer were claimed to contain copyrighted material?

Comment: There is a comment on the question saying "Post removed due to a DMCA notice from Lidl". There are also several, now deleted, images contained in the question so it might have been one of the images.

Comment: @BDL True, but from the context of the post, the deleted images seem to be lists of folders and files, and debugger output -- none of which is an obvious copyright violation. The code in the question also seems to be quite generic. Hence my question.

Comment: Did you receive any contact from the team regarding the DMCA notice? I would imagine that you should have been sent a copy if the strike is directed at your content in case you want to send a counter notice.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I never received any such notification, but it is quite possible that the request was regarding the question, and my answer got deleted along with the question.

Comment: The question contains screen shots showing directory names that could very well be from the buying department of the UK branch of Lidl, a European supermarket chain. Informing every single answerer of what happened seems like too much to ask, and to what end?

Comment: SO could publish DMCA notices [like GitHub does](https://github.com/github/dmca).

Comment: @Pekka웃 I don't expect SO to add an email notification feature for this. But I feel I put some effort into my answer, and I would like to better understand the circumstances of its removal, in this specific instance, particularly since my answer had no copyrighted content.

Comment: @Stijn most are found [here](https://lumendatabase.org/notices/search?page=4&recipient_name=Stack+Exchange&sort_by=date_received+desc&term=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F41759829&utf8=%E2%9C%93) but for this specific question I can't find a specific notice

Comment: @rene The most recent entry there from Stack Exchange is from the 27th of september 2017. It's likely no longer being actively maintained, because it's improbable there are no new DMCA notices between now and then.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth seeing how much "quality" entries there are I suspect it  could be filed in so many different places ....

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I [asked on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311707/since-when-did-se-stop-uploading-dmca-takedown-notices-to-lumen-database) why these notices aren't being uploaded.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You're probably looking for an official answer, but a quick read of the question makes it pretty obvious.

The question contains unredacted paths and screenshots of a network drive owned by Lidl, and screenshots of Excel documents. One could consider a DMCA notice to be a bit harsh given the context, but Lidl is within their rights to ask for removal of the content.

Lesson learned: if you are posting environment information from systems you do not own, redact them. Replace things with placeholders like `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: For obfuscation purposes, use RFC2606 for host and domain names, RFC 5737 for IPv4 addresses, RFC 3849 for IPv6 addresses.

Comment: @immibis If I were to publish a screenshot of a Word document containing code from iOS, who would file the DMCA notice: Microsoft or Apple? ;)

Comment: @Stijn https://i.imgur.com/WXfuedi.gif